# How to migrate from Oracle 10g databse to MySql 8 database

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, database-migration

We are currently using **Oracle 10G database** for the backend support of our application. We need to migrate the entire Oracle database schema into **MySQL database**, including all existing tables, views, procedures, triggers and sequences etc.

Can anyone kindly help me to guide the steps of migration, without hampering any schema definitions, keys and constraints etc.??

Also I came to know that MySQL does not support '*sequences*'. In that case how can we convert the sequences which are present in Oracle database?

Please don't just mention any tool name, because I found few tools online but those are really lengthy and cumbersome processes to follow. Kindly mention step-wise, so that it's understandable easily.

I used `Sql Developer IDE` earlier, but it supports the reverse way migration, that is, from MySql to Oracle, not the one I need. Hence, I could not use it.

Comment: Strongly suggest you consider MariaDB (MySQL fork by the original MySQL founder) instead of just moving from one oracle product to another.  The last few versions of  MariaDB have supported sequences, though you can do just fine without them most of the time.

Comment: That does not answer my question. The migration is a business requirement, we can not disrupt it.

Comment: I would recommend: learning mysql at least as well as you know oracle, then manually converting your schema and queries.  As far as business requirements go, MariaDB is arguably a flavor of MySQL

Comment: Yes, these are comments, not answers, which is why they are comments, not answers :)

Comment: Thank u. I will check with *MariaDB* later. But I need to migrate this one first. Manually conversion seems not possible, because the Oracle db is huge, containing a large number of tables, views etc.

Comment: you are in for a lot of pain, regardless.  if you hope for some tool to just fix things for you, you are likely to be disappointed.  hope it goes well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an Oracle Doc ID [1477151.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/SearchDocDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=1a23wgywdt_222&_afrLoop=349080988953254#FIX) for that case.

Though you asked to not mention any tool name, in that document Oracle advises to use [MySQL Migration Wizard](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration.html) and provide some script examples for manual migration in case if automatisaton won't work.

Check those out. I hope that'll help

UPD: Again, I'm aware of you asking not to mention any tool, but here's another excerpt from that doc where even Oracle clearly says you have to use a third-party tool

> Migration of Stored Procedures, Functions, Packages, Triggers, Views, Sequences must be performed using third party tools and needs manual effort. This document highlights method to perform data migration.
>
> There are a host of third party tools, some of which are open source. For example:
>
> http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-mysql
>
> http://kettle.pentaho.com/
>
> http://www.convert-in.com/ora2sql.htm
>
> http://www.ispirer.com/products/oracle-to-mysql-migration

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Understood that, need a third party tool for the migration. Will check with the links you provided. Thanks.

Comment: One more thing need to mention that,, the version of database we are using so far is the **open source** one,, not any licensed version.

Comment: @Jerry, Do you mean 10G XE?

Comment: @Jerry, yeah that makes it problematic for you to get access to the doc I've sent you. I hope you did manage it to get the info you needed. BTW, I'm not sure you can call it "open-source". Yes, it is free, but you can't get it's source code. As with PostgreSQL or SQLite for example - their source-code is open and everyone can reach it (and build his/her own database!)